# android notify a textview to be updated from the server side

Tags: android, web-services, textview

I have a `textView`, i need to display in this text a message returned by the web service, my problem is every some time this message can be changed , i need to know whether it is changed ..so the target is to create a notifier or something that tell the android app to change the displayed message in `textview` when it is changed.

how to do this from server and android sides??

Comment: create a service to update the textview

Comment: So you tell me to call the service every 1 sec?? this is not professional

Comment: I believe you dont understand what a service is, so please take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind(android.content.Intent)

Comment: so how the service can knows if the text is changed in the server?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do this. I think first and best way, when you want to change text, you may send notification application then it fire text change webservice.

Another solution is swipe refresh. This is generally using in applications and simple way.

Comment: then you have to use notification way. when it changed in your databese , your service send notification, and when notification come your application  and application is already opened, textviews call automatically your webservice.